# Razor code on asp.net view doesnt apply changes to the website

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to assign an action method to a line in a .cshtml file but despite what I put no changes are reflected on the site.

Here's the razor code:

```
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoginUser" method="get">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="loginID">ID:</label>
                <input type="texT" class="form-control" id="ID" name="id" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               
                <label for="loginPassword">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" name="sifre" required>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

At    `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>` no matter what I replace
"Login"

with no changes are reflected on the webpage. When inspecting the site on a browser

```
        <form method="post" action="/Home/Login">
            <div class="form-group">
                <style>
                    label:{width: 50px;}
                    input:{width 50px;}
                </style>
                <label for="loginID">ID:</label>
                <input type="texT" class="form-control" id="ID" name="ID" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <style>
                    label: {
                        "width: 50px;"
                    }

                    input: {
                        "width 50px;"
                    }
                </style>
                <label for="loginPassword">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" name="Password" required="">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

this is what is on the browser and it specifies the action as Home/Login when I don't even have it anywhere in my razor file

I tried to change the website markup ,launch another project and test it there but nothing helped. AND when i try to build the project on Visual Studio it says there are build errors but does not show me what the error is and still builds

Comment: When you get the build error, are you clicking “run last successful build”? Because your razor page doesn’t match the output you showed at all.

Comment: Submit type is the type of button used to submit form data. When click the submit button,browser collects form data, sends to URL.The "button" type can't submit the form, if you want the button to behave like a form submission you can use JavaScript to listen to the button's click event and call the form's Submit() method.The form you checked in the browser is not the same as the form in razor you provided. Please check whether it matches the current form.In generating project If prompted to continue or run the last successful build, choosing "No" reveals errors in the list.